# Do not redirect back button on user signin successfull

Tags: react-redux

Once the user has successfully registered the back button should not take the user to sign up unless user logout from the profile.

here the code:

```
  function checkAuth(nextState) {
  let loginUserData = window.localStorage.getItem("user")
  loginUserData = loginUserData ? JSON.parse(loginUserData) : null
  if (loginUserData !== null && loginUserData.userType === 'client') {
      if(nextState.location.pathname === `${INDEX_ROUTE}/*`){
         browserHistory.push('/')
      }else{
        console.log('not found')
      }
  } else if(loginUserData !== null && loginUserData.userType === 'freelancer' && window.localStorage.getItem('step3') === undefined) {
    if(nextState.location.pathname ==='/dashboard/payment'){
      browserHistory.push('/')
    }else{
      browserHistory.push('/dashboard')
    } 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
 <Provider store={store}>
   <Router history={history} >
      <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <Route path="/thankyou" onEnter={checkAuth} component={Thankyou} 
/>
 </Router>
 </Provider>
 </MuiThemeProvider>,
 document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try `browserHistory.pop()` after a signin

Comment: How to use browserHistory in route actually signin and signup process in  the routes checkauth function.

Comment: After a sign in, but before you push the next state